# Нормальное распределение - что это?

Tags: алгоритм

Есть задача "Построить модель системы..., в которой моменты прибытия клиентов имеют нормальное распределение...".
Объясните, пожалуйста, что это значит?
Погуглил, нашел пару формул про вероятности, но ни одна из них не является функцией от времени, или я чего-то не понял.
В итоге я сделал так: каждую минуты прибывает народу на N больше, чем в предыдущую, так до середины временного интервала, потом начинает прибывать на N меньше. 
Это же совсем не правильно? Я это сделал только потому, что функция Лапласа выглядит так, а вообще я даже не уверен, что она к этому вопросу относится :)
В общем, помогите, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

> моменты прибытия клиентов имеют нормальное распределение

Тут надо понимать так: вероятность прибытия клиента в тот или иной момент времени имеет нормальное распределение.

Известно что для нормального распределения нужны два параметра среднее (*мю*) и отклонение от среднего (*сигма в квадрате*). Их надо ввести как-нибудь из условий, например 0 (это время когда обычно прибывают клиенты) и 1 (это то на сколько они обычно отклоняются от заданного времени).

Интереснее другое как найти значение нормального распределения когда есть только равномерное (стандартная функция random возвращает случайное значение из равномерного распределения). Можно например [так п3.3](http://ermak.cs.nstu.ru/mmsa/glava3/glava3_3.htm)

Теперь (когда определена функция *F* возвращающая вероятность появления клиентов от времени) можно сказать сколько клиентов (*К*) прибудет в момент времени *t* (нужно будет только предположить сколько вообще бывает клиентов *A*)

```
K(t) = F(t)*A
```

Comment: Вы имеете в виду формулу (8) на том сайте?
Спасибо за объяснение.

Comment: Ну я имел введу весь пункт 3.3 и в частности формулу 8.